# Enforce that two functions take the same parameter types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a generic function that takes two functions as parameters and returns a result. I want the types to enforce that both functions have the **same** signature, but not what that signature **is** (other than the return type).

I can define the types this way:

```
type Func<TResult> = (...args: any[]) => TResult;

function foo<TResult>(f: Func<TResult>, g: Func<TResult>): TResult { ... }
```

Which permits the desired parameters:

```
function f1(s: string, i: number): boolean { return true; }
function g1(s: string, i: number): boolean { return false; }
foo<boolean>(f1, g1);
```

Unfortunately it also permits functions with different signatures:

```
function g2(b: boolean): boolean { return false; }
foo<boolean>(f1, g2);
```

Is it possible to allow the former call to compile but not the latter?

Note that I want this to work for **any** parameter list (empty, one parameter, two parameters, etc.), but the parameter types for both functions should match.

Comment: I agree with Titian's solution technically, but given that `foo` cannot call `f` or `g` (since it doesn't know the parameters), what can be the implementation of `foo`? How can it generate a `TResult`?

Comment: @RobNapier This is for a library like GitHub's Scientist. Type `foo` as returning `Func<TParams, TResult>` and you can return `(...args): TResult => {}` where the result comes from passing `...args` to one of the function parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add another type parameters for the parameters and use tuples in rest parameters to spread it to the function signature. This will ensure the parameter types of the two functions are the same (or at least compatible)

```
type Func<TParams extends any[], TResult> = (...args: TParams) => TResult;

function foo<TParams extends any[], TResult>(f: Func<TParams, TResult>, g: Func<TParams, TResult>): TResult {
    return null!
}

function f1(s: string, i: number): boolean { return true; }
function g1(s: string, i: number): number { return 0; }
foo(f1, g1);


function g2(b: boolean): boolean { return false; }
foo(f1, g2);
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=13#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYB4AqAFAhgJywWwGcoIAPYCBAE2KwRAG0BdAGijQCUJC4AbYAHxQAvFAAUAOim4A5oQBc7bHiIBKEUM7c+wANwAofQDNESYAEsA9gihHLl9MoLEyFarXrM2WnvwFijRXhkR1xnby5fQTYZINNQlUII7T9VRR8dKABvfSg8qBwIYDgcGwQ+XgBCfQBfQxNkC2tbAEYxBShCYBxzBBk2c0Vy-AAjCBw0qBH7Xgg6bIKikptuuAhdKDqGsysbGTaOrp6+gaG4UfHJ4bGcBcLi0qgABg2t+wCWmJbVA3rTJr2ACYxCNFNNLLM6JNwZCbFlFg8bEYsLxCOtNsZ3kZPlAZICfkA)

Comment: This works; thank you!
Interestingly the second function can have _fewer_ parameters than the first.
I assume that's to allow for optional parameters.